# Wpf highlight image?

Tags: wpf, image, graphic-effects

Is there any effect in WPF I could Make an image shiny etc.?
(I want to use it for a hovered image)

A mask or something like this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying a [BitmapEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743435.aspx) to the image, just keep in mind that they can be expensive to use.

OuterGlowBitmapEffect might help you.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/edc4ab64-4cd2-4496-ba5e-431365c782e7

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean by "shiny". A simple way is to have each image opacity set to 0.5 and change it to 1 when mouse is in.